# Best way to store many data in React Native?

Tags: database, react-native, redux, realm, react-redux

What the best way to save **big** bulk of data in react native will be in react native app?

I already tried some things and here us my thoughts:

1. Redux Store. Very easy way. But what if I will have 1000 items in array? They all will be in memory as an app state?
2. Realm. Looks nice. But also documentation says, that if I need to filter something, I need to get **all** items first and then use filter method:

---

```
let dogs = realm.objects('Dog');
let tanDogs = dogs.filtered('color = "tan" AND name BEGINSWITH "B"');
```

So with realm I also thinking how it will affect on app performance.

What you think about it? Maybe I am not right? How you store your data?

P.S. BTW in future I want to create sync with server.

Comment: Realm queries are lazy, so you don't actually "get" all items first.

Comment: Save in a server side database and make an API call to get data when you need it.

Comment: @toddmetheny It will be offline-first app

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Comment: 1000 items should be nothing for AsyncStorage.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html
Also combine with redux-persist for full offline first experience.

Comment: @mauron85 But redux-persist load data into application state? Am I right? It means that all 1000 items will be loaded into memory each time user open application.

Comment: That is correct. I was talking in general. You can blacklist/whitelist keys that should not be persisted with redux-persits.

Comment: Eventually you will need to load those items into memory anyway. Or you need only filtered subset of those items? If so, I believe there is currenly not suitable store for this. I can imagine, that somebody will write sqlite plugin for RN, that will allow this. But currently it doesn't exists yet.

Comment: @mauron85 For example you can imagine big list of TODOs. Of course they don't need to be showed at the same time. Infinite scroll can be implemented. So I think realm will be good as database, while it have built-in server sync functionality. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have no issues storing 1000 objects in Realm. It is optimized for storing large amounts of data and only loads data into memory when needed.